# Dell Inspiron 3537 not waking up after closing lid

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, sleep

A lot of people seem to have the same problem as me, however after trying everything that I have found online, it still doesn't work.

As the title suggests, I close the lid on the laptop and when I open it again the laptop is still working but the screen never wakes up and I have to force restart it.

I've already gotten the latest BIOS update and I've tried making the laptop hibernate instead of sleep when I close the lid and vice versa. Nothing works.

Comment: Is it a touchscreen? Dell touchscreens have a problem when waking up from power-saving modes: the backlighting doesn't switch on. If you look very, very closely, you might find the screen is actually working only you can't see it without the backlighting. I don't know of any fix if tis is, in fact, your issue.

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this? Have you contacted Dell Support or looked through their online support documents? Is there a BIOS update available?

Comment: @mmmason it's not a touchscreen, no.

Comment: @CharlieRB I've already gotten the latest BIOS update and I've tried making the laptop hibernate instead of sleep when I close the lid and vice versa. Nothing works.

Comment: When did this problem start? Did this laptop have Windows 7 originally?

Comment: @CharlieRB No, it had Windows 8 and it was fine initially. Then it started having this problem one day, then I upgrade to 8.1, and still it persists, even after the BIOS upgrade.

Comment: @CharlieRB It must have something to do with the sleep mode as it doesn't just happen when I close the lid, but also if I leave the laptop alone for a while. ( Though in Power Settings I have told it never to go on sleep mode )

Comment: You could try booting to an Ubuntu Live CD to find out if it is specific to Windows 8. If it is specifically related to Windows Power Management or sleep mode, ensure all drivers are correct and up to date. If that doesn't help you may want to consider repairing or doing a clean reinstall of Windows.

Comment: download and install intel video driver from dell site - should work

Comment: @jareckus I have the latest one

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of graphics driver..right click on AMD graphics adapter in device manager and uninstall by removing the previously installed files..Also remove Intel HD graphics driver (do not reboot)
And then from Add or remove programs remove all graphics related software (AMD & intel) and finally reboot your OS..You you may check your problem has been solved..You have to download and install latest version of graphics drivers again..